# Find a string from MD5 given known format of string?

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have a challenge to complete involving the obtaining of a string from a given MD5 hash.  For example, the string that I'm required to obtain in this problem has the format of: 1) a dwarf from The Hobbit, 2) a number 1-9999, and 3) a color of the rainbow.  Here is the given MD5 hash: 24c64b83434eb1dccc5beb6162c954cb

For example, in this instance the string might have the format: fili287yellow, or something similar.

Here is some Java shellcode given as a starting point to solving the challenge:

```
//Made with help from http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class md5_shellcode {

public static void main(String[] args){

    //Add your code here

}

/**
 * Md5 hash function, do not modify
 * @param dwarf Dwarf in the company of Thorin
 * @param number Number 1 - 9999
 * @param color Color of the rainbow
 * @return md5 hash of dwarf + number + color
 */
public static String md5Hash(String dwarf, int number, String color){

    try{

        MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        m.update((dwarf + number + color).getBytes());

        byte b[] = m.digest();

        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)

            s.append(Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

        return s.toString();

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("lol");

    }

    return "Error";

}

}
```

How would I solve this problem?  What would the script itself look like?

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question!  I don't usually code with objectives like these in mind, and so solving a challenge like this is pretty difficult!

Comment: This is quite broad - where, *specifically*, are you stuck?

Comment: Just on how to modify the given shellcode in general in order to find the string from the given MD5.  I know it seems really noobish to just essentially slap code up here and ask for someone to poke around it to find a solution, but I'm at a complete loss on this one.

Comment: That's not very specific...

Comment: I'm sorry :(  I would like to try and be more specific, but I'm not sure how to even approach the solution.

Comment: Brute force it: try all the combinations until you find the one that produces the given hash.

Comment: Was it specified that the names are lowercased?  It will make a difference.

Comment: Is there a tool I can use to brute force specific values/formats instead of just forcing a/A-z/Z and 0-9?

EDIT:  Yes, all characters are lowercase.

Comment: The use use of hash algorithm like MD5 is to calculate a hash code from a byte array (in this case three Strings). While this is easy the inverse function (getting the three strings from the MD5 sum) is hard. This is the basis of cryptography. While MD5 is no longer considered secure it is still hard. So the best way to figure out the original strings is brute force by checking all combinations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to decode the hash back into the string that produced it. The only way to find the answer is to try hashing different strings until you find one that produces the correct hash. I'm not going to write out a complete working solution for you, but it would have this general form:

1. Build a list of possible Dwarf names.
2. Build a list of possible colors.
3. For each combination of name, number, and color:

   1. Construct a candidate string
   2. Hash it
   3. Test whether you got the correct hash.

Your program might have the following general form:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dwarves = { "fili", ... };
    String[] colors = { "red", ... };

    for (String dwarf : dwarves) {
        for (int ii = 1; ii <= 9999; ++ii) {
            for (String color : colors) {
                String candidate = dwarf + ii + color;
                // Hash and test the candidate
            }
        }
    }
}
```